# How to split PDF into paragraphs using Tika

Tags: python, pdf, apache-tika

I have a PDF document which I am currently parsing using Tika-Python. I would like to split the document into paragraphs.

My idea is to split the document into paragraphs and then create a list of paragraphs using the `isspace()` function

I also tried splitting using `\n\n` however nothing works.

This is my current code:

```
file_data = (parser.from_file('/Users/graziellademartino/Desktop/UNIBA/Research Project/UK cases/file1.pdf'))
file_data_content = file_data['content']

paragraph = ''
for line in file_data_content:
    if line.isspace():  
        if paragraph:
            yield paragraph
            paragraph = ''
        else:
            continue
    else:
        paragraph += ' ' + line.strip()
yield paragraph
```

Comment: In the extracted text you pull from the file via tikka, is there a clear pattern that announces the location of a paragraph split? Perhaps a newline character (or maybe a pair of newline characters?) If your post-tikka text extract contains these textual clues, you might be able to make use of them via a `split` type of command.

Comment: @Thomas Kimber

I also tried to use the blankline tokeniser however paragraphs are messed up

    file_data = (parser.from_file(file))
    file_data_content = file_data['content']
    file_paragraphs = blankline_tokenize(file_data_content)

Comment: Related, could be a duplicate: [Split Documents into Paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41913668/7851470); [Correctly parse PDF paragraphs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55499989/7851470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure what `file_data_content` now looks like because I do not know what you are using to process your PDF data and what it returns. But, if it is returning a basic string, such as `Line1\nLine2\netc.`, then the following below should work. When you say:

```
for line in file_data_content:
```

and `file_data_content` is a string, you are processing the string character by character rather than line by line and that would clearly be a problem. So, you would need to split your text into a list of lines and process each element of that list:

```
def create_paragraphs(file_data_content):
    lines = file_data_content.splitlines(True)
    paragraph = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.isspace():
            if paragraph:
                yield ''.join(paragraph)
                paragraph = []
        else:
            paragraph.append(line)
    if paragraph:
        yield ''.join(paragraph)

text="""Line1
Line2

Line3
Line4


Line5"""

print(list(create_paragraphs(text)))
```

Prints:

```
['Line1\nLine2\n', 'Line3\nLine4\n', 'Line5']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  - this really help. And @Gregory thanks for linking the following case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499989/correctly-parse-pdf-paragraphs-with-python.

Answer (score 0):

```
paragraphs = file_data_content.split('.\n\n')
```